# Submit (prevented default) multiple forms with one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have multiple `forms` in my page and one button collects the data from all of them, processes it via AJAX Calls and then displays some stuff using the results.
Now I initially used `forms` (although i actually never use a direct submit on them / no `action`) to have the built-in velidators for e.g. `input type number` or `required`. This obviously doesnt work though, because i never submit the `forms`. Is there a way to manually call those validation routines for a form and only proceed if they are fulfilled?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using separate forms? One solution (besides moving everything as a child of the form) is to `trigger('submit'...) on the forms.

Answer (score 0):

The `reportValidity` method on form elements returns true if all elements in it are valid. It isn't supported in many browsers so you can use a polyfill:

```
if(!HTMLFormElement.prototype.reportValidity){
    HTMLFormElement.prototype.reportValidity = function(){
        for(var i = 0;i < this.elements.length;i++){
            if(!this.elements[i].checkValidity()){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**One form validation example**

*html:*

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
    <input type="submit" id="realSubmit" value="submit" style="display: none;" />

    <button type="button" id="customSubmit">Validate</button>
</form>
```

*javascript:*

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    return false;
});

$('#customSubmit').click(function() {
    // This will run html validations.
    $('#realSubmit').click();
});
```

I hope this can help you.